# U-SQL JsonTuple - How to access specific fields in JSON array

Tags: json, u-sql

I'm extracting AVRO data which has a JSON field that I need to get values from.  The JSON has an array, and I don't know what order the different elements of the array may appear in.  How can I target specific node/values?

For example, Filters[0] could be Category one time, but could be AddressType another time.

I'm extracting AVRO data - i.e.

```
@rs =
    EXTRACT date DateTime,
            Body byte[]
    FROM @input_file 
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.ApacheAvro.AvroExtractor(@"
 ...
```

The Body is JSON that can look like this (but Category is not always Filter[0].  This is a small example; there are 7 different types of "Field"s):

```
{
    ""TimeStamp"": ""2019-02-19T15:00:29.1067771-05:00"",
    ""Filters"": [{
            ""Operator"": ""eq"",
            ""Field"": ""Category"",
            ""Value"": ""Sale""
        }, {
            ""Operator"": ""eq"",
            ""Field"": ""AddressType"",
            ""Value"": ""Home""
        }
    ]
}
```

My U-SQL looks like this, which of course does not always work.

```
@keyvalues =
    SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Body), 
        "TimeStamp",
        "$.Filters[?(@.Field == 'Category')].Value",
        "$.Filters[?(@.Field == 'AddressType')].Value"
        ) AS message
    FROM @rs;


@results =
    SELECT 
           message["TimeStamp"] AS TimeStamp,
           message["Filters[0].Value"] AS Category,
           message["Filters[1].Value"] AS AddressType
    FROM @keyvalues;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not actually answer my question, as a workaround, I modified the Microsoft 'sample' JsonFunctions.JsonTuple method to be able to **specify my own key name** for extracted values:

```
    ///   Added - Prefix a path expression with a specified key.  Use key~$e in the expression.
    ///   eg:
    ///   JsonTuple(json, "myId~id", "myName~name")    -> field names          MAP{ {myId, 1 }, {myName, Ed } }
```

The modified code:

```
    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> ApplyPath<T>(JToken root, string path)
    {
        var keySeparatorPos = path.IndexOf("~");
        string key = null;
        var searchPath = path;
        if (keySeparatorPos > 0) // =0?if just a leading "=", i.e. no key provided, then don't parse out a key.
        {
            key = path.Substring(0, keySeparatorPos).Trim();
            searchPath = path.Substring(keySeparatorPos + 1);
        }

        // Children
        var children = SelectChildren<T>(root, searchPath);
        foreach (var token in children)
        {
            // Token => T
            var value = (T)JsonFunctions.ConvertToken(token, typeof(T));

            // Tuple(path, value)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, T>(key ?? token.Path, value);
        }
    }
```

For example, I can access vales and name them

```
@keyvalues =
    SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Body), 
        "TimeStamp",
        "EventName",
        "Plan~          $.UrlParams.plan",
        "Category~      $.Filters[?(@.Field == 'Category')].Value",
        "AddressType~   $.Filters[?(@.Field == 'AddressType')].Value"
        ) AS message
    FROM @rs;

@results =
    SELECT 
       message["TimeStamp"]     AS TimeStamp,
       message["EventName"]     AS EventName,
       message["Plan"]          AS Plan,
       message["Category"]      AS Category,
       message["AddressType"]   AS AddressType
    FROM @keyvalues;
```

(I've not tested to see what would happen if the same Field appears multiple times in the array; That won't happen in my case)